# Fortinet acces issues

Tags: ssh, vpn

My campus has now changed its VPN to Fortinet. (Old one was Global Protect.)

1. I have two older MacBooks but both upgraded to Ventura. FortiClient works fine on one (can Ccnnect, then use ssh) but not on the other, which gives me an error message that the Fortinet server can't be accessed; trying the server IP address fails too.
2. On my Linux box, Ubuntu 20.04, Fortinet connects fine, but ssh just hangs.

Any suggestions?

As mentioned, I tried a numeric IP address on Ubuntu, to no avail.

Comment: Stack Overflow is _only_ for questions about writing code. Consider [Super User](https://superuser.com) for general computing topics.